# reading BLE device data into xamarin android tablet app

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to xamarin and BLE devices and trying to create an andriod table app to connect and read the blood pressure device I bought from amazon. I looked around and got many test codes but I cannot get any name or connect to any devices that the app scans.
I am using 10" android tablet, pie 9.0, api 28, connecting to windows laptop thru usb cable.
here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <uses-permission  android:name = " android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED " />
    <uses-permission  android:name = " android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE " />
    <uses-feature  android:name = " android.hardware.bluetooth_le "  android:required = " true " />   
</manifest>
```

here is mainpage code

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
       
            _bluetoothAdapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            _bluetoothAdapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
            {
                _gattDevices.Add(a.Device);
            };
        }
```

and scan button code

```
private async void ScanButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ScanButton.IsEnabled = false;
    var locationPermissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);

    if (locationPermissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Permission required", "Application needs location permission", "OK");
        }

        var requestLocationPermissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });

        var locationPermissionPersent = requestLocationPermissionStatus.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == Permission.Location);
        if (locationPermissionPersent.Value != null)
            if (locationPermissionPersent.Value == PermissionStatus.Granted) locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }

    if (locationPermissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Permission required", "Application needs location permission", "OK");
        return;
    }

    _gattDevices.Clear();

    await _bluetoothAdapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
    listView.ItemsSource = _gattDevices.ToArray();
    ScanButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

and here is the item select code

```
private async void FoundBluetoothDevicesListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_bluetoothAdapter.IsScanning)
        await _bluetoothAdapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();

    IDevice selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as IDevice;

    try
    {
        ConnectParameters para = new ConnectParameters(true, true);
        await _bluetoothAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(selectedItem, para);
        //await _bluetoothAdapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(selectedItem);
        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new BluetoothDataPage(selectedItem));
        await DisplayAlert("Notice", "connected", "success !");
    }
    catch (DeviceConnectionException err)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Notice", err.Message, "Error !");
    }

}
```

all the proper permissions have been given.
when the scan runs, no name appears only id's and when I select an item the "success" dialog never pops and the code never reaches, it hangs on the connect call! I tried to scan for my iphone and the code does not even get the iphone name. Any help is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: You seem to be using some library for BLE, which one is it?

Comment: here are all my incudes:

Comment: using Android.Bluetooth;
using Java.Util;
using Bluetooth_Device_Scanner;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Bluetooth.LE;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Android;
//using Android.Content.PM;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions;
using Java.Nio;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Exceptions;
using System.Reflection;
using Android.Provider;